# express+angular, how to use templateURL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

The project is based on Express, and no view-engine is used.
I set some static directories:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/view'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));
```

index.js is in webroot, directoris is like:

```
/
/index.js
/public
/view
/view/index.html（index）
/view/sidebar.html
/public/js/app.js（js for index.html）
```

The index.html include scripts is like:

```
<script src="angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

The directive in index.html is:

```
<my-sidebar></my-sidebar>
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module("myBlog", ["ngRoute"]);
app.directive("mySidebar", function () {
    return  {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        templateURL: "sidebar.html",
    }
})
```

The `templateURL` doesn't work well, how can I write it, or how can I see the URL in my bower.
Tx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank u for watching my problem. I finally found that my chrome didn't work well and the code I provided is correct.
Here I provide another way which require a view engine:

```
npm install --save ejs    

app.engine('html', require('ejs').__express);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.get('/sidebar.html', function (req, res) {
   res.render('sidebar.html');
})
```

The `templateURL` send a 'GET' http request so that I can write `app.get('/sidebar.html')` to receive to request and render the html.